# Drupal 9 user guide or documentation

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-9

I have spent a lot of time on getting Drupal 9 Documentation but I could not find anything specific to Drupal 9. Module Development is what mainly am looking for.

I referred to https://www.drupal.org/docs and https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules and many more...

None of the link say anything about Drupal 9, how can I start with Drupal 9 if its already released but hard to find any documentation.

Comment: For most of the documentation you can just refer to Drupal 8. Drupal 9 is essentially Drupal 8 with a lot of breaking changes / deprecations removed.

Comment: Thanks @baikho so let me start with that...hope i dont have to rewrite my code after any of the Drupal 9 upgrades or patches...:-0

Comment: Please also see https://www.drupal.org/docs/understanding-drupal/drupal-9-resources

Comment: as per my observation there are so many blogs available for learning Drupal 8/9....duckduckgo gives better search result than google...not promoting anyone, am just  letting everyone know the things that worked for me

Comment: You can also search using https://unelmas.com, but there are many resources for creating custom components in Drupal 8/9. Check this tutorial which is cool actually: https://u16p.com/155s3dy19o

Answer (score 0):

One new way to start a custom module for Drupal 9 consists to ask Chat GPT to do that.
The version 4 is really better. It is really interesting because it is commenting every steps and generated parts of code and you can learn to become autonomous in coding with it.
When you ask Chat GPT to generate code, you can tell it a wide variety of prompts in or der to add specifics features and constraints to code. It is powerfull to start with a sort of boilerplate containing features like interacting qith node or other modules, directly into generated classes.

Comment: Yes, chat GPT will now be parallel to stack overflow. Chat GPT helps in highlighting SQL or code syntax error any many more.. It's now the first action item for a developer before posting questions on stack overflow